# linked list undefined behavior

Tags: c, linked-list, undefined-behavior

An abstract question: Say I have a singly-linked list of the nodes:

```
      #node 1      #node 2
root->[data|next]->[data|next]->NULL
```

In C, root is declared:

```
struct Node *root = NULL;
```

where *root is the Node pointer 'holding' the address "NULL".

Now, lets say that I want to remove the last node in the linked list, the following code will allow the computer to do such action:

```
//pop: pop removes last/latter node in linked list and sets new last node to NULL
void pop(struct Node *root){
    struct Node *last;
    struct Node *current = root;    //current point to same node as root

    while(current->next != NULL){
        if(current->next == NULL) {break;}    //premature break in traversing of linked list; will stop at last node
        last = current;    //last points to same node as current
        current = current->next;    //move current to next node
    }

    last->next = NULL;    //point second-to-last node to NULL, making it defacto last node in list
    free(current);    //free last node to heap

}//end pop
```

after calling pop and passing root to the function, the new linked list looks like this:

```
      #node 1
root->[data|next]->NULL
```

If the program calls pop again, we should expect the linked list to look like this:

```
root->NULL
```

However, it does not! In the case of a linked list of integer elements in order, we will call pop until we observe strange behaviour:

```
List: 1 2 3
Call pop
List: 1 2
Call pop
List: 1
Call pop
List 1980765
```

The above is an example of undefined behavoir caused by a dangling pointer. Now the question is: How can the program avoid this behaviour and produce a side-effect that close to root->NULL from popping all nodes from the linked list until said list is empty?

Comment: What does your debugger tell you when you step through your pop function?

Comment: There are several issues with your code. It would crash here `while(current->next != NULL){`  if the root is NULL and also here `last->next = NULL;` if the list has only one node since last is uninitialised.

Answer (score 1):

**First:**

This condition can never ever be true:

```
if(current->next == NULL) {break;}
```

If it was true, we wouldn't reach that line but fall out of the `while` loop.

**Second:**

If you do not execute the body of the loop at least once, your pointer `last` keeps uninitialized. Hence

```
last->next = NULL;
```

sets a random memory location to `NULL`

**Third:**

When you try to remove the last remaining element, you need to `free(root)`. But you cannot set `root` to `NULL` as it is passed by value.